# Broken commands on debian by setting PATH

Tags: bash, debian, shell, path

I've got a pretty big issue right now, I've tried setting a PATH to a python file, but I've done it wrong and seemingly broken every command on debian.

What I get when I type any command:

```
-bash: "command": No such file or directory
```

I think this might have happened when I just typed "PATH=" with nothing after the equal sign. How can I reset this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you are doing this in a graphical X session** (which is likely), you can simply close the terminal window and open a new one. Because the change to $PATH doesn't get promoted to the parent process, the new terminal session will inherit the correct value for $PATH from *its* parent process, and bash will apply any further customization from the configuration on disk.

If you **aren't running in an X session,** then the easiest solution is probably just to **log out and back on.** Unless you made changes to your bashrc or bash profile files, that will reset your $PATH to its normal value.

If for some reason you are having difficulty logging out, you can at the bash prompt just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to tell the shell to ignore any input on the current command line, followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. The latter sends an end-of-file signal to the shell, which causes it to exit. If your login shell exits, you are brought back to the login prompt and can log back on.

**If you aren't running through X and cannot log out right now** then you can start a new login shell, which will set up its own copy of the environment, including $PATH. This may be useful if you are in the middle of something and want to get to a point where you can cleanly exit and then continue. To do this, you need to run bash with the `--login` (or `-l`) parameter. Since bash won't be in your $PATH, you need to specify the full path to it. Thankfully this is pretty easy, because pretty much every modern system which has bash installed will have it at /bin/bash, so we know where to look.

- First run `exec /bin/bash --login`. This will replace your current shell with a new one, which will have mostly the correct environment. However, it's possible that your bash startup scripts rely on things which aren't available because $PATH is empty. If this is the case, it's highly likely that they will print a few (or many) errors.
- To get around that, just `exec /bin/bash --login` *again*. This should be executing in an environment where $PATH is set correctly, so the bash startup scripts will be able to run what they need. The result will be a correctly set up shell instance.

You don't really *need* to use `exec`, but it's handy here because it causes your existing shell to be *replaced* by the new one as opposed to simply launching the new instance as a subprocess. If you don't use exec in this situation, when you exit the most recently started shell, you'll be back in the broken instance.